# How do I make an abstract-override to display the result in a label in windows form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, pos

This is what I have tried:

```
 public abstract double getTotalPrice();
```

and

```
 public override double getTotalPrice()
    {

        this.discounted_price = (item_price * item_quantity) - (item_price * item_quantity * item_discount / 100);
        return discounted_price;
        
    }
```

I tried to put it in a label like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DiscountedItem di = new DiscountedItem(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text), Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text));

        
        label10.Show(di.getTotalPrice().ToString());


    }
```

When I click the button, it should compute for the total price and then, display it in a label.
I keep searching but, I can't find the exact solution to this.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. Include the relevant parts of your class hierarchy, or better yet, provide a [minimal and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
label10.Text = di.getTotalPrice().ToString();
```

instead of Show()